Showing $\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}k\frac{k-2}{2^{k-1}} = 5$. How to deal with quadratic terms?
essentially I would like to figure out how the infinite sum below is computed. Is there some generating function that allow me to compute $\sum_i^\infty i^2 k^i$ ?
$$
 \sum_{k=3}^{\infty}k\frac{k-2}{2^{k-1}} = 5$$
I know that I can rearrange this into $$\sum_{k=3} k^2/2^{k-1} - 2 \sum_{k=3} k/2^{k-1} = \sum_{k=3} k^2/2^{k-1} - 1$$ using the fact that the second summation is simply the expectation of geometric random variable parametrized by prob 1/2 substract something.

Are you familiar with the geometric series?

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

@SineoftheTime yes, I know how to compute sums of geometric series

see this for example

Hint: Denote that sum by $S$, consider $S - 2 S$.

Do you know what the variance of a Geometric random variable is? If so, that will help you evaluate a sum with a quadratic term divided by $2^k$.
